# Increase of two days for each month worked

Tags: php

I have a table of users in a database, where I have the following fields:

```
id_usuario
login
passwd
dias_disponibles (Fixed users have 24 days available)
fecha_ingreso (Date entry in company)
tipo_usuario (Fixed or Temporary)
```

Each user can make a vacation request. The user `admin` is responsible for adding the new users. My problem is with `temporary` users. A temporary user will have the available days according to the months worked up to one year. For every month worked, `dias_disponibles` is increased by 2. For example, if `user1` since joining the company, it has been working for 2 months now it will have 4 `dias_disponibles` and so on until it takes 12 months, then from there, it will always be 24 `dias_disponibles` . I have this function that calculates the difference of months since I joined the company until today:

```
function difmeses($fechaingreso){
$fechainicial = new DateTime($fechaingreso);

$fechaactual = (new DateTime)->format('Y-m-d H:i');
$fechafinal = new DateTime($fechaactual);

$diferencia = $fechainicial->diff($fechafinal);

$meses = ( $diferencia->y * 12 ) + $diferencia->m;

return $meses;
}
```

My question is what to use so that it increases until 12 months in the company, if it takes 12 months, stop. Any help on how to do the 2-day increment, `for`, `while`, `sql` ... ??

Comment: Did you try anything, with for or while or sql?

Comment: I thought about trying it with a while but I do not know how to structure the loop. With sql I have been told that it could also be done

Comment: try this `for($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++){$meses = $meses + 2;} `

Comment: But what I want is to add 2 to the available days of each user, not the months. It is assumed that the loop is so that every time 1 month passes, 2 days are added to available days

Comment: For example, a loop that uses the function that I created and when it verifies that a month has passed since it adds 2 days to days available with this sql:

`update sec_users set dias_disponibles = dias_disponibles + 2 where login = 'user1'`